# JavaScript, Regex - `.replace` is only removing the last-matched part (when multiple matches)

Tags: javascript, regex

I am modifying a music player to not show anything in a song's title after a dash, or opening parentheses.

Expected Results:

```
Bennie And The Jets - Remastered 2014

// Becomes 

Bennie And The Jets

----

The 59th Street Bridge Song (Feelin' Groovy)

// Becomes 

The 59th Street Bridge Song

----

December, 1963 (Oh What A Night!) - 2007 Remastered Version

// Becomes 

December, 1963

----

Ave Verum

// Becomes (remains...)   

Ave Verum
```

The code I am using to make the modifications:

```
var song = 'some song name';

var title = function() {
    var str = song;

    var re = /(.*)(\s+((-|\()[^-\(]*))/g;

    str = str.replace(re, '$1');

    return str;
};
```

Which returns:

```
Bennie And The Jets

----

The 59th Street Bridge Song

----

December, 1963 (Oh What A Night!)

----

Ave Verum
```

The third case - where there is *both* a hyphen or a parentheses - falls short.

How can I force it to take the *furthest-forward* match (and, thus, everything following)?

**Additionally (Edit #1)**

The player does not insert spaces before the hyphen in hyphenated songs, and so the condition preceding the hyphen is

```
\s+ //One or more
```

**Final Solution and Use (Edit #2)**

*(Solution)*

Courtesy of [Andy Ray](https://stackoverflow.com/users/743464/andy-ray), the final regex is:

```
var re2 = /\s*[(-].*$/;
```

*(Use - For anyone with the same distaste for trailing song modifiers)*

The offending music player is [Spotify Player](https://www.spotify.com/us/) (for Mac, but this *should* work identically the same for other platforms). You can make changes like this 'cause the app is written as a [Chrome Embedded Framework (CEF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chromium_Embedded_Framework).

CEF is basically a website - HTML, CSS and (most importantly) JavaScript. Because if this, you can play around a bit, try things out, customize the things they won't normally let you customize.

*NOTE!!*

*The following process and code will NOT change your song titles anywhere else except for within the app, on the device you make the changes. All your account details are pulled from servers every time you open it.*

On a Mac, the files of interest will be found in:

```
/Applications/Spotify.app/Contents/Resources/Apps
```

Where you will find a bunch of files with the extension `.spa`. These aren't actually files, but rather zipped directories containing the pertinent stuffs.

I unzipped them using [The Unarchiver](https://unarchiver.c3.cx/commandline)

```
// In terminal
cd /Applications/Spotify.app/Contents/Resources/Apps
find ./ -name \*.spa -exec unar {} \; // Or just the couple you need
find ./ -name \*.spa -exec rm {} \; // Be careful!
```

The Spotify app will run exactly the same, whether you have the zipped or unzipped directories.

To modify the song titles (specifically in the "Songs" and "Playlist" views), you'll want to look in:

```
collection-songs/bundle.js
playlist-desktop/bundle.js
```

Inside of both files, there is ***only one** reference to `track.name`. A quick find will get you to where you need to be. These lines are your offenders.

In both files, change the line:

```
name: track.name,
```

To:

```
name: function() {
        var re1 = new RegExp('^' + '\\(.*\\).*', 'i')
        var re1_2 = /(\((.*)\))/
        var re2 = /\s*[(-].*$/g;

        var str = track.name;

        if(re1.test(str)) {
            str = str.replace(re1_2, '$2');
        }

        str = str.replace(re2, '');

        return str;
    },
```

And that's it, all done.

You start out with

[image: Spotify Before]

And come out with

[image: Spotify After]

*NOTE!!*

The question I was asking about above only dealt with:

```
var re2 = /\s*[(-].*$/g;
```

The reason for the two preceding regex expressions (`re1` and `re1_2`) are because some songs (few!) have leading brackets:

```
(Everything I Do) I Do It For You
```

The two expressions, along with

```
if(re1.test(str)) {
    str = str.replace(re1_2, '$2');
}
```

Makes it look like

```
Everything I Do I Do It For You
```

If that isn't a concern, you can just take those lines out.

This little hack might not be pretty in code, but sure is nice to look at in the app.

Comment: The code you've pasted is invalid. You make a variable named `var re2` but then use an undefined variable `re` in `replace(re, '$1');`

Comment: @AndyRay sorry, copy and paste error. Will fix.

Comment: If you have an answer, post it as an answer, not in the question. Also, we do not need markers inside your question for every edit you made. If people are interested in the edit history they can view the edit history.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think there are much simpler solutions to your problem.

Why not just replace anything at the end of the string, starting from a dash or an open paren, with nothing?

```
str.replace( /\s*[(-].*$/, '' );
```

Explanation:

```
\s* Any whitespace found before a paren or a -
[(-] either of the two characters "(" or "-"
.*$ everything else up to the end of the string
```

Additionally you could do this with a simple `.substr()` and `.indexOf` check for those characters.

Comment: Yep, I was trying to be too clever. Obvious once you see it. I've modified is slightly to only occur if at least one preceding space. The player lists hyphenated titles without spaces (i.e. Ana-Lisa). `/\s+[(-].*$/` did the trick.

Answer (score 0):

`.*` is *greedy*, meaning it will match as much as possible consistent with the rest of the pattern matching. So it matches everything up to the last `-` or `(` in the input.

Use `.*?` to make it non-greedy, so it will match the smallest amount.

```
var re2 = /(.*?)(\s+((-|\()[^-\(]*))/g;
```

Comment: Using this, identically to what you've provided (to account for any mis-typings), provides `December, 1963- 2007 Remastered Version` for the third case

Comment: It's because of the `[^-\(]`, which fails for any condition where there is more than one trigger character. `/(.*?)(\s+((-|\()(.*)))/g` works (allowing all chars)

Comment: Right. Your regexp is designed to allow multiple titles on the same line.